# Can't pass array as a parameter of a class

Tags: php

I cannot pass an array as a parameter into the class, and I have no idea how to do it.  I am writing this because it tells me that this post is mostly code and I cannot post it, so I need to add more details.

Human:

```
class Human{
    protected $height;
    protected $weight;
    protected $age;
    protected $gender;
    protected $nat;

    public function __construct($height,$weight,$age,$gender,$nat){
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->weight = $weight;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->gender = $gender;
        $this->nat = $nat;    
    }

    //toString method
    public function __toString(){
        return 
        "height: ".$this->height.
        " meters;<br /> weight: ".$this->weight.
        ";<br /> age: ".$this->age.
        ";<br /> gender: ".$this->gender.
        ";<br /> nationality: ".$this->nat;
    }

    //GET methods
    public function getHeight(){ 
        return $this->height; 
    }
    public function getWeight(){ 
        return $this->weight; 
    }
    public function getAge(){ 
        return $this->age; 
    }
    public function getGender(){ 
        return $this->gender; 
    }
    public function getNat(){ 
        return $this->nat; 
    }

    //SET methods
    public function setHeight($height){ 
        $this->height = $height;
    }
    public function setWeight($weight){ 
        $this->weight = $weight; 
    }
    public function setAge($age){ 
        $this->age = $age; 
    }
    public function setGender($gender){ 
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }
    public function setNationality($nat){ 
        $this->nationality = $nat;
    } 
}
```

Student:

```
class Student extends Human{
    private $uni;
    private $year;
    private $faculty; 

    public function __construct($height,$weight,$age,$gender,$nat,$uni,$year,$faculty){
        parent::__construct($height,$weight,$age,$gender,$nat,$uni,$year,$faculty);
        $this->uni = $uni;
        $this->year = $year;
        $this->faculty = $faculty;    
    }  

    public function __toString(){
        return 
        "height: ".$this->height.
        " meters;<br /> weight: ".$this->weight.
        ";<br /> age: ".$this->age.
        ";<br /> gender: ".$this->gender.
        ";<br /> nationality: ".$this->nat.
        ";<br /> university: ".$this->uni.
        ";<br /> year: ".$this->year.
        ";<br /> faculty: ".$this->faculty;

    }

    //GET methods
    public function getUni(){
        return $this->uni;    
    }
    public function getYear(){
        return $this->year;    
    }
    public function getFaculty(){
        return $this->faculty;
    }

    //SET methods
    public function setUni($uni){
        $this->uni = $uni;        
    }
    public function setYear($year){
        $this->year = $year;    
    }
    public function setFaculty($faculty){
        $this->faculty = $faculty;    
    }

    //adding year of studying to student
    public function add($year){
        $this->year = $year;
        $year++; 
        echo $year;;    
    }
}
```

Programmer:

```
class Programmer extends Human{
    public $lang = array("PHP/SQL", "Java", "C#", "HTML/CSS", "Javascript");
    private $exp;
    private $salary;
    private $company;

    public function __construct($height,$weight,$age,$gender,$nat,$lang,$exp,$salary,$company){
        parent::__construct($height,$weight,$age,$gender,$nat,$lang,$exp,$salary,$company);
        $this->lang = $lang;
        $this->exp = $exp;
        $this->salary = $salary;
        $this->company = $company;    
    }  

    public function __toString(){
        return 
        "height: ".$this->height.
        " meters;<br /> weight: ".$this->weight.
        ";<br /> age: ".$this->age.
        ";<br /> gender: ".$this->gender.
        ";<br /> nationality: ".$this->nat.
        ";<br /> languages: ".$this->lang;
        ";<br /> experience: ".$this->exp;
        ";<br /> salary: ".$this->salary;
        ";<br /> company: ".$this->company;

    } 

    //get aarray
    public function getArr($lang){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($lang); $i++){
            echo "element s indeksom $i raven: ".$i."<br />";
            echo $i;    
        }
    }   
}
```

Code:

```
$human = new Human(1.75, 80, 22, "male", "australian");
echo $human; echo "<br />";
echo "-------------------<br />";

$student = new Student(1.70, 90, 24, "female", "british", "harvard", 3, "IT");
echo $student; echo "<br />";
echo "-------------------<br />";

echo $student->getYear(); echo "<br />";
echo $student->add(3); echo "<br />";
echo "-------------------<br />";

//i cant pass array as a parameter
$programmer = new Programmer(1.80, 70, 27, "male", "british", 2, 5,10000,"Google");
echo $programmer; echo "<br />";   
echo $programmer->getArr(1);
```

Comment: What array are you talking about?

Comment: public $lang = array("PHP/SQL", "Java", "C#", "HTML/CSS", "Javascript");

Comment: And what? How this array is connected with the class you provided?

Comment: im kinda new to the php, and programming overall, so i still dont know alot of things :)

Comment: actually, i somehow managed to post not the whole code :D (this is my first post here had some problems, now it tells me i need to wait 90 mins to post again), so ill post the beginning of the code in comment

Comment: <?php
    class Human{
        protected $height;
        protected $weight;
        protected $age;
        protected $gender;
        protected $nat;
        
        public function __construct($height,$weight,$age,$gender,$nat){
            $this->height = $height;
            $this->weight = $weight;
            $this->age = $age;
            $this->gender = $gender;
            $this->nat = $nat;    
        }

Comment: So you have this classes. What's the problem with array you're talking about? Where and how do you pass it?

Comment: i passed it into a class(english is not my native so i might be saying something wrong :D) and i need it to output, whatever is written in the array, copy that code, run it, and u will see, the array simply doesnt work, when i create object and give it some values, i dont know how to make the object output the original values of the array

Comment: Maybe asking on ru.stackoverflow.com will help?

Comment: You can't "echo" an array directly, only the individual elements; or you can implode it to a string which can be echoed

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get your problem, but I'll try to fix something with your code.

You said that you can't pass array to a function. The only function in your classes that can work with array is `getArr($lang)`.

Your problem in calling `getArr(1)` is that `1` is considered an array, which you want to iterate. But `1` is not an array, `1` is just an integer.

So you should think again what do you want to do in your function `getArr`:

- show all elements of array, which is passed an argument
- show element from `$lang` class property with index, passed as argument.

**Update:**

Okay, so if you want `getArr` function show all languages from predefined class property `$lang` then you don't need to pass it as an argument, as class instance already aware of it, so you can rewrite your function accordingly:

```
public function getArr() {
    // use $this->lang to access $lang property
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->lang); $i++) {
        // access $i element of array with []-notation
        echo "element s indeksom $i raven: " . $this->lang[$i] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Another **update**:

your `public function __construct($height,$weight,$age,$gender,$nat,$lang`
for class `Programmer` has `$lang` argument. And you passed value `2` in it. So, `$this->lang` becomes `2`, which is not an array too. Why do you do it?

Comment: i just wrote 1, because it asked for a parameter, and im far from understanding OOP, as u see i cant even ask a proper question of what i need my program to do, but ill try, so , i need the program to output values that i pass into the object, but one of the parameters of the class is array which has predefined values, and i need those predefined values to be echoed/printed or whatever u may call it, so it shows the amount of languages the programmer knows,

Comment: i need the array to put its values, without asking me to pass a value into constructor, cos i alrdy declared and assigned values to that array, but how to get them printed?

Comment: i tried that update script earlier, it doesnt make any changes,

Comment: What does your script show if you rewrite your function as i said?

Comment: i tried that way earlier, same results, nothing changes

Comment: so the object is the thing that outputs the values of parameters right? and one of those parameters is an ARRAY, and i need my object($programmer) to output the values of that array, just like it outputs the values of $exp, $salary, $company, have u debugged the code?

Comment: i did it because i had no idea what else to do and at those points when i dont know what exactly to do, i try out everything that comes to my mind, sometimes it works and i analyze and understand it, and sometimes it makes me bang my head against the wall :D just like now, so im asking you what to do :D can u make that program output the array elements, the way they should be?

Comment: Comment `$this->lang = $lang;` in your constructor.

Comment: it gives me a notice: array to string conversion, but it still works, so php automatically converts it ?

Comment: Here `";<br /> languages: ".$this->lang;`

Comment: yep i commented that .$this->lang; out, and everything is fine, but now i noticed , it stops printing parameters that come after the array,(experience is getting printed, but salaray and company do not, have no idea why, im horrible at programming....)

Comment: Please read and understand your code, You don't concatenate `salary` and `company` with other vars.

Comment: ye i just realized, it was not about understanding, just a mechanical mistake :D instead of period i used semicolon :D

Comment: what does downvote on question mean ? that it has been asked and answered before ? or it is an unclear/poorly constructed question(which it surely is)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```
$programmer = new Programmer(1.80, 70, 27, "male", "british", array('HTML/CSS', 'PHP/SQL'), 5, 10000, "Google");
```

Comment: yes i tried to do that, in theory, but anyways i got the result i wanted, just removed the array from an object, and echoed it on its own